# How to replace any character (e.g. ":") with new line in bash variable pattern substitution?

Tags: regex, bash, variables

I would like to replace ":" with a new line in $PATH using variable pattern substitution

```
echo ${PATH/:/"<WHAT TO PUT HERE>"}
```

I tried:

```
echo ${PATH/:/"\n"}
```

But that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use quoted strings just like anywhere else.

```
echo "${PATH//:/
/}"
```

For improved legibility, try this:

```
echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
```

(You probably want to substitute the colon everywhere, not just the first occurrence.  Hence, `//` not `/`.)

Comment: Can I ask you where can I read about this. Specifically how did you know that // replace all occurances :) ?

Comment: Bash has a manual page and an [on-line reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use POSIX strings (`$'`...`'`) in the substitution; they support C-style backslash sequences:

```
echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
```

I used `//` instead of `/` so that it would replace all colons, not just the first.

Comment: Here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion.  The relevant bit: `${parameter/pattern/string}
The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string. If pattern begins with ‘/’, all matches of pattern are replaced with string.`

Answer (score 0):

I realize the question has been updated to exclude these solutions, but I am leaving them up here for anyone else who is curious.

Using `sed`:

```
echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g'
```

Using `tr`:

```
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
```

Comment: I have seen it done inside the ${}. I would have looked at the man of ${}  if I knew how this construct is called... do u know?

Comment: I have never seen a specific name for it, but I would guess you could Google for variable substitution.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need :

```
printf ${PATH//:/'\n'}
```